# Convert accordion to vertical display?

Tags: html, css

I don't know if this is possible but I was wondering if it's at all possible to simply convert a vertical accordion to a normal horizontal nav or such still keeping the original CSS and html.

I just want it to display horizontally instead of vertically. Tried floating some elements and creating a div for each but could net get it working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```js
$(function() {
var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
this.el = el || {};
this.multiple = multiple || false;


var links = this.el.find('.link');
// Event
links.on('click', {el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple}, this.dropdown)
}

Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
var $el = e.data.el;
$this = $(this),
$next = $this.next();

$next.slideToggle();
$this.parent().toggleClass('open');

if (!e.data.multiple) {
$el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
};
}

var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), false);
});
```

```css
ul {
list-style-type: none;
}

a {
color: #b63b4d;
text-decoration: none;
}


h1 {
color: #FFF;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: 400;
text-align: center;
}

 

h1 a {
color: #c12c42;
font-size: 16px;
}

.accordion {
width: 100%;
max-width: 300px;
background: #FFF;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;

margin-right: 100px;
}

.accordion .link {
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
padding: 15px 15px 15px 42px;
color: #4D4D4D;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 700;
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
position: relative;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.accordion li:last-child .link {
border-bottom: 0;
}

.accordion li i {
position: absolute;

float: left;
top: 16px;
left: 12px;
font-size: 18px;
color: #595959;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.accordion li i.fa-chevron-down {
right: 12px;
left: auto;
font-size: 16px;
}

.accordion li.open .link {
color: #b63b4d;
}

.accordion li.open i {
color: #b63b4d;
}
.accordion li.open i.fa-chevron-down {
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.accordion li.default .submenu {display: block;}


/**
* Submenu
-----------------------------*/
.submenu {
display: none;
background: #444359;
font-size: 14px;
}

.submenu li {
border-bottom: 1px solid #4b4a5e;
}

.submenu a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #d9d9d9;
padding: 12px;
padding-left: 42px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.submenu a:hover {
background: #b63b4d;
color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
<li>
<div class="link"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>Home<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
<ul class="submenu">
<li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
<li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="default open">
<div class="link"><i class="fa fa-code"></i>Profile<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
<ul class="submenu">
<li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
<li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Frameworks javascript</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<div class="link"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>History<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
<ul class="submenu">
<li><a href="#">Tablets</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Desktops/a></li>
<li><a href="#">Test</a></li>

</ul>
</li>
<li><div class="link"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>External Sites<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
<ul class="submenu">
<li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Bing</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Yahoo</a></li>
<li><a href="#">GMAIL</a></li>

</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is remove `max-width` from parent and put `.accordion > li` to be inlined:

```
.accordion {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.accordion > li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
    this.el = el || {};
    this.multiple = multiple || false;


    var links = this.el.find('.link');
    // Event
    links.on('click', {
      el: this.el,
      multiple: this.multiple
    }, this.dropdown)
  }

  Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
    var $el = e.data.el;
    $this = $(this),
      $next = $this.next();

    $next.slideToggle();
    $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

    if (!e.data.multiple) {
      $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
    };
  }

  var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), false);
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  color: #b63b4d;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 a {
  color: #c12c42;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.accordion .link {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 42px;
  color: #4D4D4D;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.accordion li:last-child .link {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.accordion li i {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  top: 16px;
  left: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #595959;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.accordion li i.fa-chevron-down {
  right: 12px;
  left: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.accordion li.open .link {
  color: #b63b4d;
}

.accordion li.open i {
  color: #b63b4d;
}

.accordion li.open i.fa-chevron-down {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.accordion li.default .submenu {
  display: block;
}


/**
* Submenu
-----------------------------*/

.submenu {
  display: none;
  background: #444359;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.submenu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4b4a5e;
}

.submenu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 42px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background: #b63b4d;
  color: #FFF;
}

/** ADDED CODE */
.accordion {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.accordion > li {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
  <li>
    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>Home<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="default open">
    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-code"></i>Profile<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Frameworks javascript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>History<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Tablets</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Desktops/a></li>
<li><a href="#">Test</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>External Sites<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Yahoo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">GMAIL</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! It's displaying vertically now.